# Visual Studio HTML shortcut notations

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've been watching a few videos recently and have seen people using text editors and using shorthand notation to quickly markup html.

For example

```
.my-panel
```

becomes

```
<div class='my-panel'></div>
```

in the editor window.  This is fantastic I thought...if only I could do this in Visual Studio.  Anyway, I decided to try this in VS and low in behold it works!!

Can anyone tell me where I can find more documentation on this?  I've tried to locate it but I don't even know what to Google??

Note: You must press tab after typing out the shorthand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called Zen Coding, it's part of Web Essentials.

Link: http://vswebessentials.com/features/html